# Discord.py: Is there a way to send a image from CatAPI to chat with a discord bot?

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm running into problems when I try to send an image from Cat API. It gives me the error:   **TypeError: Aliases of a command must be a list or a tuple of string**

Here's the code I've got so far.

```
@client.command(aliases = 'cat')
async def catpic(ctx):
    cat_image = cat.getCat(format)
    await ctx.send(cat_image)
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the aliases kwarg takes a list or tuple of strings, putting 'cat' inside a list should resolve this.

```
@client.command(aliases=['cat'])
async def catpic(ctx):
    cat_image = cat.getCat(format)
    await ctx.send(cat_image)
```

Comment: Flagging this error

`AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'rstrip'` , I don't understand what the means exactly.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few errors. I'm not familiar with the cat API, so please pardon me. First, your aliases are to be in a list, not a single string:

```py
@client.command(aliases=['cat'])  # This is a list, just add to the end to make more aliases
async def catpic(ctx):
    cat_image = cat.getCat(format)
    await ctx.send(cat_image)
```

Next, when sending an image, make sure to use the `file` parameter to a Discord message:

```py
@client.command(aliases=['cat'])
async def catpic(ctx):
    cat_image = cat.getCat(format)
    await ctx.send(file=cat_image)
```

But this will depend on what the cat API will return. If it returns an image, then you should be good. If not, then you may need some readjustments.

Answer (score 0):

The error you have specifically asked about regarding the command aliases was answered but there are also a few other issues with your command.

Assuming you are using the `random-cat` module, `getCat()` is expecting a string, however you have passed it a built-in function called `format`, which resulted in the `AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'rstrip'` error you mentioned in a comment. See the [random-cat repository](https://github.com/gravmatt/random-cat#usage) on how the function should be used.

The second issue is that `getCat()` returns the path to the .png file it saved the query to, so the only thing your command would be doing is downloading an image, and then sending a message with the file path to that image on your computer. To actually upload the picture, you will need to pass that filepath to a [`discord.File`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.File), and then use the `file` parameter when sending:

```py
filepath = cat.getCat()
file = discord.File(filepath)
await ctx.send(file=file)
```

Finally, the third issue is that you are using a **blocking** library to make queries to TheCatAPI. This will result in your bot temporarily being unresponsive as it queries for an image. For a small-scale bot, this will likely not be an issue, however you should keep this in mind in case your users start noticing slow responses when someone uses your command.

If you do want to resolve this, you will have to use an *asynchronous* library to make your own HTTP requests such as `aiohttp`, which already comes installed as a dependency of discord.py. The other bonus with this is that you won't need to download the actual image, as the response provides a direct link to the image which can be sent instead.

Comment: It's flagging me an error, but I think it's because I entered it in wrong. Could you edit the answer and show how the entire command works (e.i the whole @command spiel)? Also, this was the error: `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden.`

Comment: @goose.mp4 That error message means the bot tried doing something with the discord API that it isn't authorized to do, such as trying to send a message to a channel without the required permissions. The other two lines I didn't show (`@client.command(...)` and `async def ...`) shouldn't be related to your error but the other answers already have it done correctly.

Comment: The other answer is actually someone I know, and we discovered that the answer he gave doesn't actually work. It should work but it doesn't. It just says forbidden and that's all we know.